# Dificuldade para mover personagem em tabuleiro

Tags: c

Tenho uma matriz de estruturas como tabuleiro. 
Meu personagem começa na posição [0][0]:

```
tabuleiro[0][0] = personagem;
```

[image: Tabuleiro inicialmente]

O personagem é exibido corretamente em sua posição inicial, mas não consigo movê-lo utilizando o código abaixo (está incompleto, mas deveria funcionar até onde fiz):

```
void movimentar(criatura tabuleiro[][10], criatura personagem){
system("cls");
imprime(tabuleiro);
criatura vazio;
int i=0, j=0;
char mover;

printf("Use WASD ou as setas do teclado para se mover pelo tabuleiro!\n");
scanf(" %c",&mover);

if(mover=='s'){
    tabuleiro[i+1][j]= personagem;
    i++;
}
imprime(tabuleiro);
system("pause");            
}
```

O tabuleiro e o personagem são definidos algumas funções acima. Mais ou menos dessa forma (tirei o que considero menos relevante):

```
criatura tabuleiro[5][10];
    criatura personagem;
    criatura chefe;
    criatura vazio; // isto aqui adicionei recentemente, ainda preciso verificar se faz sentido criar uma "criatura vazio" para colocá-la no local de onde o personagem saiu.
    vazio.classe = ' ';

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(j=0;j<10;j++){
            tabuleiro[i][j].status = 0; // aqui o tabuleiro todo é dado como desconhecido, a princípio (utilizo 0 como status para aquilo que não está visível).
            tabuleiro[i][j].classe = ' '; 
        }
    }

    // ATRIBUTOS PERSONAGEM 
    personagem.classe = classeE;
    personagem.atc = atcE;
    personagem.def = defE;
    personagem.saude = saudeE;
    personagem.status = 1;
    tabuleiro[0][0] = personagem;
```

Quando aperto o s, o personagem permanece na mesma posição e um espaço em branco aparece do outro lado do tabuleiro.

[image: tabuleiro após tentar mover personagem]

A função para imprimir o tabuleiro é, em parte, esta:

```
for(j=0;j<10;j++){
            if(tabuleiro[i][j].status == 0){
                printf(" ?  ");
            }
            else{
                if(tabuleiro[i][j].classe=='X'){// X -> armadilha de grande potencial ofensivo
                    printf(" X  ");
                }
                else if(tabuleiro[i][j].classe=='x'){ // x -> armadilha de pequeno potencial ofensivo
                    printf(" x  ");
                }
                else if(tabuleiro[i][j].classe=='i'){//i -> inimigo
                    printf("%c_%c ",155,155);
                }
                else if(tabuleiro[i][j].elixir == 'e'){ // e -> elixir
                    printf(" %c  ",3);
                }
                else if(tabuleiro[i][j].classe == 'C'){ //C -> Chefe
                    printf("%c_%c ",227,224);
                }   
                else if(tabuleiro[i][j].classe == ' '){
                    printf("   ");
                }       
                else if(tabuleiro[i][j].classe=='g' || tabuleiro[i][j].classe=='b' || tabuleiro[i][j].classe=='p'){ // g,b ou p -> herói
                    printf("^_^ ");
                }
            }
        }
```

O status do personagem é definido como 1 no início do código, para que ele seja visível. Não copiei o código todo aqui pois seria muita coisa, é possível saber o que está dando errado apenas com essas informações?

@edit: troquei

```
if(mover=='s'){
    tabuleiro[i+1][j]= personagem;
    i++;
}
```

por

```
 if(mover=='s'){
        tabuleiro[i+1][j] = personagem;
        tabuleiro[i+1][j].classe = 'g'; // onde g é a classe guerreiro
        tabuleiro[i][j].classe = ' ';
        i++;
    }
```

e parece estar "funcionando", apenas não tenho certeza se está da maneira correta...

Comment: De onde vem o `i` e o `j` que estão associados nessa tentativa de movimentação?

Comment: A princípio ambos são definidos como 0, visto que a posição inicial do personagem sempre será [0][0].

Comment: Mas e quanto à atualização dele? Ele não deve se manter com esses valores a vida toda. Tem como por mais contexto ao redor desse trecho do `mover`? Para saber como as variáveis se relacionam, de onde vem, para onde vão

Comment: É verdade! Pensei, então, em colocar um i++ após o tabuleiro[i+1][j]= personagem; no if do "s". A princípio eu tinha pensado em fazer um for para verificar onde o personagem está, mas a posição inicial é sempre conhecida, então penso que é possível trabalhar alterando apenas o valor do i e do j partindo do 0,0, nesse caso. Irei atualizar o post com mais informações // @JeffersonQuesado adicionei novas informações.

Comment: Já posso dizer que a função `movimentar` está errada. Você não tem persistência da posição atual do jogador, então ele não pode, digamos ir duas vezes para baixo. Não sei se vou conseguir elaborar uma resposta em tempo, mas recomendo que você guarde no próprio jogador qual a sua posição atual.

Comment: Obrigado @JeffersonQuesado, acabei notando isso quando fui tentar movimentar aqui. A solução que encontrei foi passar os valores da linha e coluna por ponteiro: int *lin, int *col 
Depois os armazeno em variáveis int dentro da função:
int l = *lin;
int c = *col;
Por fim, fiz a movimentação da seguinte forma:
if(tabuleiro[l+1][c].classe == ' '){
    tabuleiro[l+1][c] = personagem;
    tabuleiro[l+1][c].classe = classeE;
    tabuleiro[l][c].classe = ' ';
    l++;
    *lin = l;

Parece ter funcionado! edit: aqui nos comentários fica complicado de ler, vou adicionar nas respostas

Comment: Sua ideia de `criatura vazia` pode ser comparável a algo como um [`Objeto Nulo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que encontrei foi a seguinte:

```
void movimentar(criatura tabuleiro[][10], criatura personagem,char classeE, int *saudeE, int *atcE, int *defE, int *lin, int *col, int *elixir){ // linha e coluna passados aqui
    system("cls");
    imprime(tabuleiro);
    criatura vazio;
    int l = *lin; 
    int c = *col;
    char mover;
    int retirar;
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Use W, A, S, ou D para se mover pelo tabuleiro!\n");
    scanf(" %c",&mover);

    if(mover=='s' || mover =='S' ){
        if(l+1<=5){
            if(tabuleiro[l+1][c].classe == ' '){ // a movimentação ocorre diretamente se o local para onde o usuário deseja ir não existe inimigo
                tabuleiro[l+1][c] = personagem;
                tabuleiro[l+1][c].classe = classeE; // classeE é a classe escolhida pelo usuário no início do jogo
                tabuleiro[l][c].classe = ' ';
                l++;
                *lin = l; // salvando o valor de volta na função anterior
```

Não sei se essa solução está realmente adequada, mas até agora tem funcionado bem. Criei outros ifs para movimentar para os outros lados e tomei cuidado com todos os casos especiais que imaginei.